# Augmented Lagrangian Method for Inequality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Augmented Lagrangian Method can be used with inequality constraints. The question is how.

One approach (according to Numerical Optimization Book by Nocedal and Wright; page 522), is linearly constrained Lagrangian. Description is shown in the attached image. The question is what $A_k$ in the formulation 17.55b? I do not find any description for that:

[image]

Comment: Tangential question, but what do you need to know this for?  What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: "according to Nocedal" Please do not assume that people know the book just by its author. Include the title.

Comment: @ littleO  I want to understand how I can use Augmented Lagrangian, when  I have inequality constraints, using this method. The equivalent question is how does LCL work exactly.

Comment: @ Michael, Good point! fixed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A_k$ should be an approximation of the Jacobian of $c$ at $x_k$. For the first look, you can think of $\nabla c(x_k)^\top$. Then, the constraint is just the first-order Taylor expansion of $c$ at $x_k$.